# Unable to start SQL server 2019 docker

Tags: sql-server, docker

Installed docker in Centos 7.

1. docker setup for SQL server based on this url [Microsoft docker link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-docker?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. Docker is converted to Non-root user

Still Error is shown for permissions as below

SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.
This container is running as user mssql.
/opt/mssql/bin/permissions_check.sh: line 59: exec: -v: invalid option
exec: usage: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: What's on line 59 of `/opt/mssql/bin/permissions_check.sh`?

Comment: That line is empty. I have checked this section. That is actually last line. What I strong believe is the access issue to the /var mounted place.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for all your suggestions.

I get error

```
    /opt/mssql/bin/permissions_check.sh: line 59: exec: --: invalid option
```

But, in my case, I found answer in [docker forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/mssql-server-exiting-after-run-command/86324/2).

And, my full command for start docker is:

```
    sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=******" 
    -v /Data/mssql:/var/opt/mssql/data 
    -p 1433:1433 
    --name sql1 
    -h sql1 
    -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest 
    --restart=always
```

And short answer looks as "the parameter --restart=always **can't** be the end of the sentence"

In common words, error "invalid option" means a general error in the docker command and may not be a container-specific error.

In my case, other arguments order help me:

```
    sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=******" -v /Data/mssql:/var/opt/mssql/data -p 1433:1433 --restart=always --name sql1 -h sql1 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for all the helps provided. It was due to the permissions issue to the mounted folder from non-root user.

Alternative approach is taken instead of /var/opt path, went on with approach of SQLvolume. So permissions/non-root user permissions issues

Comment: I'm facing the same issue; What steps you took to fix this issue?

Comment: Instead of giving direct Path, Give SQLVolume reference. That will resolve issue.  like below docker run  -v sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql

Comment: Great. Thank you.